# I'm scheduled to fly Wednesday from New York City to Doha to Cairo. Will they reroute us?

Tags: event-based-effects, cairo

I'm on a group tour with Colette travel through AAA. We leave Wednesday via JFK to Doha to Cairo. Will they reroute us or cancel the whole trip?

Comment: What did Colette travel say when you asked them?

Comment: Thought it was all up to Qatar airways and if they could fly around Doha into other airspace. No one's giving us much information

Comment: ... because of the war in Israel? Some other reason?

Comment: Why would they fly “around Doha”? What’s the problem in Doha?

Answer (score 2):

Yesterday all 4 flights from JFK to Doha (American Airlines, Qatar Airways) operated normally with a few minor delays. It looks like the route is fully operational at the moment.

[image]